# Connecting thermostat to two hot wires

Tags: thermostat

I am replacing a thermostat with a basic single line break thermostat and my electrical box has only has two hot wires each carrying 120 V.  The wiring diagram of the thermostat calls for connecting the hot wire to L1 marked on the thermostat.  Since I have two hot wires is it ok to wire either one to either of the thermostat wires?

The thermostat I am replacing was already wired this way but I am wondering if it was done right.

[image]

Comment: What make and model is your new thermostat?

Comment: Honeywell CT410A

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box the old thermostat was mounted to please?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/179XUZVqPktjAck96

Comment: Please [edit] your post and use [diy.se]'s built in hosting to embed the image (click the "sun & mountain" icon above the text entry box) instead of making people chase down links and look for them in the comments. Not everyone reads all the comments, and they can get deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You should be fine connecting it either way around

Since this is a mechanical thermostat, it should work just fine wired in either way around; of course, if it doesn't work, you can try swapping the wires so they are connected to the other terminal.